# how to change the background color of dropdown-content menu in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me to find out.

This is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown">//I used Bootstrap
 <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" onClick="myFunction()" onMouseOver="showlinks()" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-radius:15px 0px 15px 0px; background-color:transparent; border-color:grey">Menu                
<span class="caret">
   </span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you please accept the edit request.Because your code is not fully displayed.We can only see when we click on edit.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, make sure your `bootstrap.css` file is referenced before any custom CSS file you write. You can then **override** Bootstrap's styling by being more specific and using parent / child selectors to ensure your style overrides Bootstrap's, i.e.:

**CSS:**

```
.header .top-nav ul.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmcjLxsw/

EDIT: FYI - doing it this way makes sure you don't have to use `!important`, which can tale element styles out of the cascading flow of a document's layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick change try this `<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:#000000!important;" >` and when you're changing background you will need yo change the text color so if you need to after this! Important; add this color:#ffffff!important;

Comment: Please, never use !important, is the worst practice ever

Comment: @EnriqueQuero - I completely agree... I avoid !important as much as physically possible...

Comment: So press ctrl+f and type dropdown-menu you will find the class and edit it

Comment: But if you can't edit the css because it is a example.min.css you can unmin the css on this site http://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/ to edit it easy

Answer (score 0):

Please erase  `background-color:transparent` in button

**HTML**

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" onClick="myFunction()" onMouseOver="showlinks()" type="button"ata-toggle="dropdown"style="border-radius:15px 0px 15px 0px; border-color:#fff">Menu                
    <span class="caret">
    </span>
        </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown ul li
 {
   background-color:#000;
  }

.btn-primary
 {
  color:#fff;
 } 
.btn-primary:hover
{
  background:#003259;
  color:#fff;
}
```